# Google map API resize doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-api

I have implement google map API.
I actually have two maps loading on the same page.
One is directly shown when you load the page.
The second is show when you click on a button. then a modal with the map appear.
the modal is display none then display block after click.
The map appear but no in fullsize.
Here is my js that append the google map.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lat1,lon1,lat2,lon2) {
            var R = 6371;
            var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);
            var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1); 
            var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2); 
            var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a)); 
            var d = R * c;
            return d.toFixed(0);
        }

        function deg2rad(deg) {
          return deg * (Math.PI/180)
        }

        function initialize() {
            $('.map_canvas').each(function(index, Element) {
                var markers = new Array();
                var map_canvas = Element;
                var map_options = {
                    center: new google.maps.LatLng(<?php echo !empty($user['coord'][0]) ? $user['coord'][0] : '0' ; ?>, <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][1]) ? $user['coord'][1] : '0'; ?>),
                    zoom: 12,
                    scrollwheel: false,
                    mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
                };

                var map = new google.maps.Map(map_canvas, map_options);

                if (navigator.geolocation) {
                    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position) {
                        markers = [
                            ['user', <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][0]) ? $user['coord'][0] : '0' ; ?>, <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][1]) ? $user['coord'][1] : '0'; ?>],
                            ['you', position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude]
                        ];

                        var dist = getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(
                            <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][0]) ? $user['coord'][0] : '0' ; ?>,
                            <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][1]) ? $user['coord'][1] : '0'; ?>,
                            position.coords.latitude,
                            position.coords.longitude
                        );

                        $('#left-content-map h2').append("<span class='medium-500 lower-case'> à " + dist + " KM</span>");

                        for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                            var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                            marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                                position: position,
                                map: map,
                            });
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    markers = [
                        ['user', <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][0]) ? $user['coord'][0] : '0' ; ?>, <?php echo !empty($user['coord'][1]) ? $user['coord'][1] : '0'; ?>],
                    ];

                    for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
                        var position = new google.maps.LatLng(markers[i][1], markers[i][2]);
                        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                            position: position,
                            map: map,
                        });
                    }
                }

                google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "resize", function() {
                    var center = map.getCenter();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                    map.setCenter(center);
                });
            });

            var open = false;
            $("#show-full-map").on("click", function(){
                modal.init($('#full-map'))
                modal.popup(function(map) {
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                }););
                open = true;
            });

            $('.close-modal').on("click", function(){
                modal.popin();
                open = false;
            });
        }

        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
});
```

Thank you for your futur response.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so i found the solution.

I just add a setTimeout which one execute a function that trigger the resize event.

```
$("#show-full-map").on("click", function(){
            modal.init($('#full-map'))
            modal.popup();
            var refresh = function() {
                var center = map.getCenter();
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, "resize");
                    map.setCenter(center);
                }
                setTimeout(refresh, 500);
                open = true;
            });
```

Comment: thanks for this man, this works well for me, we're on the same page , i thought resize thingy wont work for me but it's just need some time to fix itself,thanks for this buddy!

Answer (score 0):

my situation is a bit different, but at least here's another option to try if nothing helps:

I was using "resize" thing to update my controls position after change (or customization) to invalidate the map and update controls positions. But one day I've noticed that it doesn't work anymore. Nothing happens after triggering the "resize".

After spending several hours I finally solved it (now it updates all the map controls anytime I want):

```
mapInstance.setMapTypeId(mapInstance.mapTypeId);
```

this single line is enough, no need to do any other stuff (like trigger resize or setZoom/setCenter).

PS: I used this for google maps v3.34